# JS/Jquery magic line not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this css/jquery menu with a line (bottom border) that slides under the menu item on hover:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
<ul class="group" id="example-one">
<li><a href="http://www.link-host.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/web-hosting">Web Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="/vps-hosting">VPS Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="/clients/">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

here is the menu in a fiddle: *http://jsfiddle.net/asJkH/*

when one of the links is set as the current page (active link) the line stays under that link but if you refresh the page the line moves right to the end and it longer which makes the page much longer.

it doesnt seem to work right in the fiddle but if you copy and paste the code into a webpage and view it locally or on a web server it works fine.

how can i stop it from displaying the line in the wrong place if the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what you said the problem still exist when you view the page locally. When a link is clicked, if you move your mouse indicator towards menu while navigating, you see the problem; line is going anywhere.

It seems you should change your `.hover` functions. When you write `$("#example-one li").find("a")` you got an array and I think you should choose a unique link. My suggestion is to use `$("#example-one .current_page_item").find("a")` instead.